# FineUploaderS3 (4.4) Accept Header in Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm having a problem with FineUploader 4.4 in Firefox. As you know, Firefox sends the following HTTP accept header by default:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

But since AmazonS3 returns JSON data after I upload a file via POST with FineUploader, I need to override FineUploader to send an **application/json** Accept header:

```
 $('#demoUploader').fineUploaderS3({
                autoUpload: true,
                request: {
                    endpoint: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp",
                    accessKey: "AKIAJ4VQLGW68A2Y6JLQ",
                    customHeaders: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
                },
    ... etc
```

But this is not working. FineUploaderS3 ignores my **customHeader** option and still sends the default Accept header. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the accept header causing an issue for you, and what is the specific issue?

Comment: @RayNicholus because my client side Javascriptt code is expecting JSON from the Amazon S3 response, but instead of JSON I'm getting XML back from AmazonS3. I just want my JSON response :)

Comment: First off, Fine Uploader handles the response from Amazon directly.  Second, Amazon only returns XML in its responses, not JSON.

Comment: @RayNicholus Ah ok, I see! But why are the Key and Name properties in the 'response' missing only in Firefox? I have: 

.on("complete", function (event, id, name, response) where response.Key and response.Name are present in other browsers but not in Firefox. How do I get those values?

Comment: If you aren't seeing these values in your onComplete handler, then your server is not returning them in response to Fine Uploader's upload success request.

Comment: That's it! Thanks, indeed Firefox was sending an XML Accept header to my uploadSuccess endpoint which needed to be a JSON accept header. It works now, thanks!

Comment: Please include your comment as an answer so others may benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks @RayNicholus

I had to add the **customHeaders** option to my uploadSuccess endpoint in order to force Firefox to send the application/json Accept header.

```
uploadSuccess: {
    endpoint: "/api/amazons3/uploadSuccessful",
    customHeaders: { 'accept': 'application/json' }
},
```

Comment: Note that Fine Uploader sets this accept header for you as of v5.0.  https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/8b6ca26006bd789400549a4037e3a0a62771f4f4/client/js/uploadsuccess.ajax.requester.js#L71